# how to update the property of the view model when I use a value converter?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, valueconverter

I have a textBox and I use a value converter to set the text property, because this value depends on the selección of a datagrid. So I use this code:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,26,0,0" Name="myTxt" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=Principal, Path=DataContext.OneProperty, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
```

Normallt I use this way:

```
Text="{Binding myProperty}"
```

But in this case I need a converter but also I would like to update a property in the dataContext.

Is that possible or if I use a converter I can't update a property in the dataContext?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I try to be a bit clerer.

I have a view that has a TextBox. I want to set this textBox according to a converter. This converter use a property in the view model called myDataGridSelectedItems. But I have other property in the view model called myTextBox that I want to be updated when the textBox update its value with the value that it receives from the converver.

So I want to binding the Text property of the view to two properties in the view model.

Comment: If this is silverlight you need to specify Mode=TwoWay on your binding and ensure your converter implements ConvertBack and it should work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Implement the `ConvertBack` method in your value converter, which by the way should implement `IValueConverter`.

Also, specify the `NotifyPropertyChanged` binding's property to a on-key-press method.

And, the last thing, set the mode of binding to `TwoWay`.

Comment: but How can I say to the view that I want to binding the property myProperty in the view model when I use the binding to execute the converter? I mean  that the text proerty in the view binding to the convert value, but I want to binding a property in the view model too.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía  you think you are bind `myConverter <=> TextBlock` but  you are actually bind `myProperty <= myConverter => TextBlock`